# How to find cylinder and plane surface equation from parametric representation of a curve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, parametric

> Given the curve $c(t)=\langle sint+1,2-cost,sint+1\rangle$
>   find cylinder and plane surface equation.

The cylinder is easy:
$$
\cos t=2-y\\\sin t=x-1 
$$
then cylinder equation is $(x-1)^2+(2-y)^2=1$.
But what about the plane?

It looks like $z=x$ so is it correct that the plane is $z=x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point $(1,1,1)$ is on the curve, $ t= 0$.

Equation of a plane passing through $ (1,1,1)$ with normal vector  $\vec n$:

$n \cdot ( \vec r - (1,1,1)) = 0$.

Every point $\vec r(t)$ of the curve

lies in the plane:

$\vec n \dot ( \sin(t), 1- \cos(t), \sin(t)) = 0$.

With $\vec n := (a,b,c)$ we find:

$(a + c) \sin(t) + b (1- \cos(t)) = 0$ ,

$0 \le t \lt 2π.$

$(a+c) \sin(t) -b\cos(t) = - b$.

$t =π/2$:  $a + c = - b$ ;

$t = π$ : $b = -b,$  hence $b= 0$.

$\vec n = a(1,0,-1)$.

Plane:

$(1,0,-1)( (x,y,z) - (1,1,1)) = 0$;

$(x-1) - (z-1) = 0$;

$x- z = 0$.

Makes sense?

Comment: It does make sense but I wonder if all those calculations you did involving finding the normal vector are necessary if we know that $z=x$ in the first place. I was just asking if the fact that $z=x$ in terms of the coordinates of the curve implies that $z=x$ in Cartesian

Comment: Yos. OK. z=x by inspecting the curve could be a straight  line in the x-z plane. The desired plane passes through this line,. Out of the family of planes , rotating the plane around the line, which one to choose? Don't we need a normal?